# Cómo añadir instancias de Edittext a un array en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, array, edittext

Creé un array para Edittext con este codigo

```
EditText[] Informacion;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .........
    Informacion = new EditText[]{createEditView(R.id.informacion_huerto),
            createEditView(R.id.informacion_propietario),
            createEditView(R.id.informacion_ubicacion)};
    Informacion[0].setText("091783172831");
}

public EditText createEditView(int id){
    EditText texto = (EditText) findViewById(id);
    return texto;
}
```

¿Quiero saber como añado mas Edittext sin tener que rehacerla?

Comment: Los arreglos son de longitud fija. Lo mas recomendable cuando no se conoce el tamaño de la colección y se desea agregar y quitar elementos es usar una lista tipo ArrayList<T>

Comment: ¿me darias un ejemplo de como seria?

Comment: Si utilizas GOOGLE:arraylist java Encontraras varias fuentes. Por ejemplo esta: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp